# SQL Datename within a function

Tags: sql, t-sql, report

I'm having issues when trying to get a datename Month within a conversion.

My current query is used to check the time a Trolled passed 'South Shop' however I now require the query to take the conversion then display me the month only.

Current query snippet:

```
dbo.fn_ConvertUTCtoShopDateTime( Visit.ORGID,
        dbo.fn_GetTrolleyreportcrossingafter ( Visit.ORGID

                                        ,Visit.Trolley_ORGID
                                        ,'South Shop'
                                        , TrolleyMovement.ActualStartDateUTC
                                        , 90
                                       ))                                     AS [Month2],
```

I understand I can use Datename(mm, but I'm having issues when inserting it into the query.

any assistance would be fantastic

Update-----
The answer was the following:

```
Datename(mm, (dbo.fn_ConvertUTCtoShopDateTime( Visit.ORGID,
        dbo.fn_GetTrolleyreportcrossingafter ( Visit.ORGID

                                        ,Visit.Trolley_ORGID
                                        ,'South Shop'
                                        , TrolleyMovement.ActualStartDateUTC
                                        , 90
                                       ))                                     AS [Month2],
```

I apologise for my idiocy

Comment: could you please provide your table structure and some test data, also the rest of your query if possible

Comment: @JeremyC. I apologise for this question, it looks as if I've now figured it out. The answer was as below:

Comment: no problem man, glad you figured it out yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologise but the answer was is as follows:

```
Datename(mm, (dbo.fn_ConvertUTCtoShopDateTime( Visit.ORGID,
        dbo.fn_GetTrolleyreportcrossingafter ( Visit.ORGID

                                        ,Visit.Trolley_ORGID
                                        ,'South Shop'
                                        , TrolleyMovement.ActualStartDateUTC
                                        , 90
                                       ))                                     AS [Month2],
```